# select value validation in jquery-select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

For tagging functionality, I am using bootstrap select2 plugin. I have tags like

```
Process1,
Process2,
Process3, 
Process4,
ALL
```

Code : 
http://jsfiddle.net/WQZUB/

If user select "all", then he/she could not be allowed to select another options.
How to implement this functionality using `bootstrap-select2` js plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is all in your code??

Comment: Jsfiddle will be nice..!... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Use the 'change' event. 'Added' and 'removed' are inside the event object as written in the doc : http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ . Just code your algo with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at here : http://jsfiddle.net/WQZUB/1/

As I said in comment : Used 'change' event

```
$(function() {
        $('.select2_notifyAfter').select2({
            placeholder: "Notify After",
            allowClear: true
        });

        $('.select2_notifyAfter').on('change', function(e){
               if( e.val.indexOf('4') >= 0 )
               {
                  $('.select2_notifyAfter').select2("val", "4");
               }
        });
    });
```

PS : I used `"4"` because     `<option value="4">ALL</option>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give some value for all option which is there is select.

Then check the value on change of dropdown. and see whether it contains all.

```
$("selector").select2("val")
```

If it contains all then disable using below code.

```
$("selector").select2("enable", false);
```